using active win possible get url on windows and linux platform
using active win possible get url on windows and linux platform  (code language electron js)
I am expecting getting url of browser on windows and linux platform this active-win is working on mac but not working on windows and linux

The issue you're facing is that active-win is not working on Windows and Linux, but it is working on Mac. This is because active-win uses different approaches to get the active window's metadata on different platforms.
On Mac, active-win uses the Accessibility API, which is enabled by default. However, on Windows and Linux, it uses a different approach that requires additional setup.
To make active-win work on Windows and Linux, you need to ensure that the Accessibility permission is enabled for your Electron app. You can do this by adding the following code to your Electron app:
import { activeWindow } from 'active-win';

app.commandLine.appendSwitch('enable-features', 'Accessibility');
app.accessibilitySupportEnabled = true;

async function getUrl() {
  const windowInfo = await activeWindow();
  console.log(windowInfo.url);
}

getUrl();

JFYI: active-win package is deprecated and Renamed to get-windows

please show me full code and output

@ShivaniAre  i have shared necessary code now you need to try and check by your self.

i am still not able to get the url on ubuntu linux
